# React Native - Dropdown Value change doesn't reset the state of the subcomponents

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-state, react-native-textinput, react-native-picker-select

Let's say I have a RNPickerSelect component on which I switch between subcomponents.

The values of the subcomponents are 1. Flight and 2. Car

The problem is: If switch from flight to car, the state of the components inside Flight don't reset but instead keep their values. For example if I write 'Test' in the Airline Field -> I switch to Car value in the dropdown and I comeback to the Flight one, the value is still there.

Flight component:

```
 const [routes, setRoutes] = useState<IRoute[]>([initialRoute]);
    {routes.map((value: IFlightRoute, index: number) => (
     <RouteFields airline={value.airline} setAirline={airline => setFieldValue(airline, 'airline', value.id, routes, setRoutes)}/>
       ))}
```

The setField Function that is used to reset the airline state

```
export const setFieldValue = (
  value: string,
  field: string,
  id: number,
  routes: IRoute[],
  setRoutes: (updatedRoutes: IRoute[]) => void
): void => {
  const updatedRoutes = routes.map(rt => {
    if (rt.id === id) {
      rt[field] = value;
    }
    return rt;
  });
  setRoutes(updatedRoutes);
};
```

The content of RouteFields

```
<FlightAirline setAirline={setAirline} airline={airline} />
```

And the Airline component itself

```
<Airline airline={airline} setAirline={setAirline} emptyField={emptyAirline} />

export const Airline = ({ setAirline, airline }: AirlineProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      title={getAirline + ' (optional)'}
      value={airline}
      onChangeText={el => {
        setAirline(el);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

I have tried to add this to the Airline component but it doesn't do the trick when I switch the RNPickerSelect value

```
  navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    setAirline('');
  });
  navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    setAirline('');
  });
```

Comment: Could you post the code involving the picker? From whats presented it doesnt look like that changing the picker's value will trigger navigation, which is why your navigation listeners dont do the job. I think what you want to do is `useEffect(()=>setAirline(''),[pickerValue])` so that whenever the picker value changes, airLine is reset

Comment: or add `setAirline('')` to your `onValueChange` function in your picker

Comment: Thank you. I did the solution in your first comment and it worked.